# Why some function definitions appears in italic font in qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am using qt creator to work on open source and I am not able to understand some functions name are in italic fonts while declared it in it's class, whereas all other function are in normal font in all other class while declaring. Can you please explain how this functions are different from other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, QtCreator makes functions italic that are either

- Virtual methods (e.g. "virtual void foo();" ), or
- methods that are derived from a base class and then overridden in the child class (however, i'm not sure if it only happens if they are derived "virtual", or if there are other corner cases where overridden methods are not italic).